# Is it better to check if file exists before deleting it

Tags: unix, rm

Sometimes when I want to delete a file (from within a script), I will just delete it rather than checking if it exists first. So I do this:

```
$ rm "temp.txt" 2>/dev/null
```

Instead of this:

```
[ -f "temp.txt" ] && rm "temp.txt"
```

I just feel it's a waste of time to go and check if the file exists and return an exit code.

So, perhaps it's quicker to do it the first way, especially if most of the time, the file is likely to be present.

Are there any other advantages (or downsides) to do it one way or the other?

Am I wrong to think it will ever be quicker?

Comment: You still have to be prepared for the possibility that the file exists at the time of the check but no longer exists at the time of the unlink system call. It's unlikely, but you shouldn't fail completely if it happens.

Comment: rm only 'needs' -f because its aliased  to rm -i. If I do rm 2>/dev/nul and the file exists, then i need an extra carriage return to get back to a prompt. And what does `[ -f "temp.txt" ] && rm "temp.txt"` mean? i suppose you mean rm -f not just -f. And why rm twice. I don't see what you're getting at. And in *nix I thought it's single quotes not double quotes, though I see double quotes works(tested in knoppix).

Comment: @barlop - 1) my **`rm`** is not aliased to **`rm -i`**, so an "Enter" is not necessary to dismiss the rm prompt. 2) I only have 1 **`rm`** in each case, so I don't know what you mean about using **`rm`** twice. 3) **`[ -f "temp.txt" ] && rm "temp.txt"`** is to only run **`rm`** if file exists, I do NOT mean **`[ rm -f "temp.txt" ] &&...`**. 4) Double-quotes... I am just in the habit of always using Double-quotes ("...") to quote filenames because filenames may contain one or more embedded apostrophe ('). In this example, I could have used either.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - Thanks for catching my missing **`&&`**. I am sure it was there when I was writing it, but I must have somehow lost it before posting.

Comment: @barlop `[` is generally a symlink to (or equivalent of) `test`, so `[ -f x ]` is equivalent to `test -f x ]`, and the final `]` is ignored. So the same command could be written `test -f "temp.txt" && rm "temp.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?

```
$ rm -f "temp.txt"
```

So you don't have to check, nor redirect error output.

Answer (score 2):

There are really two cases:

- The file to remove is expected to exist. In such situation, the script shouldn't ignore the error but should handle the situation appropriately. For example the file system where the file was to be created is full or the process that was supposed to create the file crashed, or whatever.
- The file to remove might exist or not, in which case there is no point testing its existence.

Comment: You write " the script shouldn't ignore the error and handle it properly."   <-- Do you mean the script shouldn't ignore the error and SHOULD handle it properly?

Comment: @barlop sentence rephrased to clarify.

Comment: In the case I am talking about, it's not that I "expect" that the file "should" exist, but only that I expect it will exist most of the time. What I mean, is that the file will hold something temporary, and after running the script a few times, the temporary file will usually be present the next time the script is run. But, I do see your point about the case where it might be considered an error if the file is NOT pre-existing.